# Remove HTML from string -- comments

Tags: c#, html, .net

I have the following text which still contains some HTML code:

```
v\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
o\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
w\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
.shape {behavior:url(#default#VML);}


Hi There,
 
For the product team to have any chance in analysing this issue we need clarification on how to reproduce the problem.
```

My code at the moment is:

```
string replacedEmailText = Regex.Replace(emailText, @"<(.|\n)*?>", string.Empty);
string finalText = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(replacedEmailText);
```

How do I remove the top lines containing :

```
v\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
```

?

Comment: Note: If you have further regex-related questions, then use the `regex` tag, you will get answers much faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this specific example, you could use `.*;}(\r\n|\r|\n)*` as your replacement pattern.

However, this will fail, when the text contains the sequence `;}`. If this is possible, you might want to go further into detail on how the html lines look like:

`.*\(#default#VML\);}(\r\n|\r|\n)*`

Explanation:

- `.*`: matches any character except for new line and carriage return zero ore more consecutive times
- `\(#default#VML\);}`: matches the sequence (#default#VML)
- `(\r\n|\r|\n)*`: removes new line and carriage return zero or more consecutive times

Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/INDOY0/2)

Answer (score 0):

Do not try to strip HTML from text using regex, use some whitelisting library like https://github.com/mganss/HtmlSanitizer